# MediaPlayer on Single Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-mediaplayer

I am implementing a game, and I want to use one and only one MediaPlayer instance, running in a separate thread from the UI.  Each audio file is sent to a FIFO queue, and played immediately if no file is playing, or as soon as the previous file in the queue is finished.
I have implemented a singleton class to support this as follows:

```
public class ThePlayer {
private static ThePlayer instance = null;
private Context context;
Thread playerThread;
BlockingQueue<Integer> listIDs = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>();
MediaPlayer player;
Integer playID; 

private ThePlayer() {
    player = null;
    playerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        //Object locker = new Object();
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    playID = listIDs.take(); // blocks if list empty
                    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Took ID 0x" + Integer.toHexString(playID));
                    player = MediaPlayer.create(context, playID); 
                    player.setOnCompletionListener(
                            new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                        mp.release();
                                        mp = null;
                                        synchronized (playerThread) {
                                            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Finished playing 0x"+Integer.toHexString(playID));
                                            playerThread.interrupt();
                                        }
                                }
                            });
                    player.start();
                    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Started playing 0x"+Integer.toHexString(playID));
                    synchronized (this) {
                        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Now wait to finish");
                        wait(); // until finished playing
                    }                       
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Player thread wait interrupted");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    playerThread.setName("PlayerThread");
    playerThread.start();
}


public static ThePlayer getInstance()
{
    if(instance == null)
    {
        instance = new ThePlayer();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void play(Context _ctx, int id) {
    context = _ctx;
    listIDs.add(id);
    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Added ID 0x" + Integer.toHexString(id));
}

public void stop() {
    //TODO: implement
}
```

}

In general, this works well, but one particular file fails to play in an inconsistent manner.  In other words, in most cases, it does not play, but occasionally it does.  All the log entries indicate that the file is queued, the MediaPlayer is allocated and started, and that the onCompletion function is called.  At no point is an exception thrown.
This happens on a Motorola Defy+ phone and various emulator configurations.  It does not happen on my  Samsung Galaxy Tab II 10.1, and my guess is that is a function of more capable hardware, or possibly the more advanced version of Android.

Comment: `context` is null because currently not initializing at the time of Object creation of ThePlayer class

Comment: Just to make sure, I inserted a log, and the relevant call to play does get a non-null context.  The call to create() would have returned a null instance if the context were not valid.

Comment: Alternatively, I would be happy to see a suggestion for gracefully degrading solution.  For example, is it possible to query the hardware to find out how many MediaPlayer instances can be allocated?